# Import error with PySide inside IDA Pro

Tags: python, pyside, importerror, qtgui, ida

I have a weird error inside IDA-Pro. I've installed PySide with pip, as recommended in the official documentation.

The following command runs fine in a terminal:

```
C:\>python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PySide import QtGui
```

But inside IDA Pro (Windows > Output Window), it fails:

```
Python>from PySide import QtGui
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: La proc?dure sp?cifi?e est introuvable.
```

Though, I'm able to import PySide (still in IDA Pro):

```
Python>import PySide
```

I've created following environment variables:

```
PATH:
  [REMOVED];C:\Python27;C:\Python27\scripts;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PySide

PYTHONPATH:
  C:\Python27\Lib;C:\Python27\DLLs;C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk;c:\Python27\Lib\flare;c:\Python27\Lib\vivisect;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PySide
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Side note: [ida] is the preferred tag ([ida] and [ida-pro] should be synonyms; see: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308568/pro-ida-ida-pro)

Comment: Thanks for the advise. Fixed!

Answer (score 1):

I have finally fixed my issue by re-installing Python from scratch and then re-installing IDA Pro. I have documented the installation process here in case it could help people having the error: http://www.aldeid.com/wiki/IDA-Pro